# Problem with subprocess.call, not working as intended

Tags: python, youtube-dl

The same command string works fine on terminal(macOS) but not inside Python script

```
youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[height<=480]+bestaudio" "video link" -o "download folder" --referer "referer url"
```

works fine on terminal

but on python script it outputs the error:

```
subprocess.call(f'''youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[height<={video_resolution}]+bestaudio" "{(url)}" -o "{path}/{id}.mp4" --referer "{(url)}"''', timeout=900)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Comment: well, you do need a comma between parameters

Comment: but it's working on windows? @UlugToprak

Comment: Just for completeness try to add `shell=True`

Comment: That did the trick, thank you @UlugToprak

Comment: There is however security concerns about this. You should check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36008455/6139043)